# subset relations among Sobolev spaces and their duals

Tags: functional-analysis

This may be a rather dense question, but I would nevertheless be grateful for some guidance.

The question has to do with the Sobolev spaces $H^m (\Omega)$ on an open bounded domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $m \geq 0$ is integer.  These are Hilbert spaces; thus the Riesz representation theorem tells us that there is a one-to-one and onto correspondence between elements of $H^m (\Omega)$ and elements of its dual $H^{-m} (\Omega)$.  Yet, we also have the inclusion property $H^{m} (\Omega) \subset L_2 (\Omega) \subset H^{-m} (\Omega)$ (e.g. Oden and Reddy, Intro. to the Mathematical Theory of Finite Elements, p. 108).  How can both of these hold?  In other words, how can there be a one-to-one and onto correspondence between $H^m (\Omega)$ and $H^{-m} (\Omega)$, and yet the former is a strict subset of the latter?

Comment: That's a problem pretty much every one learning about Sobolev spaces seems to encounter sooner or later, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26280/on-the-properties-of-the-sobolev-spaces-hs).

Comment: @user14178: A bijection is not the same thing as equality. The set of all even numbers is in bijection with the set of all numbers, but is also a proper subset. (This is one of the possible definitions for an infinite set.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dual space is the space of continuous linear functionals, and for a statement like $H^m \subset (H^m)^*$ to make sense one has to define a way to interpret functions as functionals, i.e. a linear embedding $H^m \to (H^m)^*$. There are two seemingly natural candidates:
$$i_R(u)(v):=\left < u,v \right >_{H^m}$$
and
$$i_D(u)(v):=\left < u,v \right >_{L^2}$$
The strictness of the inclusion translates to the question whether the embedding is an isomorphism, and it turns out that $i_R$ is an isomorphism according to the representation theorem, but $i_D$ is not! However, in accordance with distribution theory, $i_D$ is universally used to identify functions with functionals.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and the clear explanation.  The apparent paradox is resolved by realizing that the inclusions are effected with the L_2 duality pairing and not the H^1, as you said.